# Cloudformation YAML !Sub !Ref error where two resource values require variable substitution

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

In my S3 Policy the below lines

```
Resource:
 - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::website-${paramEnvironment}/*'
 - { Environment: !Ref paramEnvironment}
 - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::website-${paramEnvironment}'
 - { Environment: !Ref paramEnvironment}
```

produce `Invalid Policy Syntax`

I'm unable to locate an example YML where there are two resources declared with variable substitution, and I have attempted variants of the above based on [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do with `{ Environment: !Ref paramEnvironment}`, but the valid `Resource` would be:

```
 Resource:
   - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::website-${paramEnvironment}/*'
   - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::website-${paramEnvironment}'
```

This is based on the assumption that `paramEnvironment` is an existing CFN parameter, and the remaining sections of the IAM policy (not shown) are correct.

The other long possibility would be:

```
Resource:
 - !Sub
   - 'arn:aws:s3:::website-${Environment}/*'
   - Environment: !Ref paramEnvironment
 - !Sub
   - 'arn:aws:s3:::website-${Environment}'
   - Environment: !Ref paramEnvironment
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcin! that was it! - in our existing templates the convention was {Environment: !Ref paramEnvironment}